# I want to make a command that deletes a channel discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Here is what I got so far
It is saying that "await" is outside of async function and I am just confused on how to fix this. I copied part of the code from a giveaway command because that is my only source of Q&A code I have

````
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def cdelete(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title = Which channel would you like to delete?)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

answer = []

def check(m):

    return m.author == cx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
        await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Timeout. Please run the command again")
    else:
        answer.append(message.content)
    try:
        c_id= int(answer[0][2:-1])
        await ctx.channel.delete
        await ctx.send("Channel Deleted")
    except:
        await ctx.send("Thats not a valid channel!")```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a command you can make it a lot easier if you just execute a command with the channel name. You can have a look at the following:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def cdelete(ctx, channel_name):
    """Deletes a channel by name or ID."""
    channel_id = int(''.join(i for i in channel_name if i.isdigit())) # Get channel ID
    existing_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) # Get channel ID with defined method
    if existing_channel: # If channel with the name/ID exists
        await existing_channel.delete()
    else: # If the channel does not exist
        await ctx.send(f'**No channel named `{channel_name}` was found.**')
```

We have a method to catch the channel ID and also pass that in as a valid argument. If the ID or channel name then exists we delete the channel.

You can here either mention the channel or pass in the ID.
Usage would be: `cdelete #channel/ID`.

If you want to avoid a long console output if you input no channel/ID/name you can build in an error handler:

```py
@cdelete.error
async def cdelete_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You need to name a channel.")
```

Comment: That worked, but just a little error message about channel_name is a required missing argument but thank you for helping out

Comment: The error message just appears if you do not pass in an ID, channel name or name of a channel, no worries. (If you just run `cdelete` it will give you that message)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is with the `check()` function. According to the doc you only can use await inside of an async function. To solve the problem change `def check(m):` into `async def check(m):`

Comment: There’s not an await inside the check func, also it can’t be a coroutine, wait_for will not await it and thus it will not work

Comment: Thanks ill try that out and see

Comment: did not seem to work, thank you for the effort